# Merging a HTTPS redirect with WWW redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I currently have this in my .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This ensures all http://www.example.com is redirected to http://example.com

I would like to implement an SSL certificate and I found this is the rewrite rule I must use for http to redirect to https.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

How could I merge the HTTPS condition with my current condition so that

http://www.example.com redirects to https://example.com

http://example.com redirects to https://example.com

If it is not possible to merge this, can I just have those two code snippets one after another?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use them one after another. I'd also save your users a redirect by having your first set of rules send them straight to HTTPS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```